# How to send Microdata event using facebook conversions api?

Tags: node.js, e-commerce, facebook-opengraph, facebook-pixel, facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

I have already set up Facebook pixel in my website but currently the events are being sent by the browser. To reduce redundancy such as events being blocked due to adblockers and other browser restrictions, I want to implement the conversions api. There are already examples on how to send standard events such as ViewContent, PageView, Purchase etc using the conversions api but I'd like to know how to send Microdata event. My main purpose for using Facebook pixel is to automatically update my commerce product catalog.

I am using React with NEXT.JS in my website and hence looking for solutions in node.js context.